# Is there a way to create a bool function that takes two List objects and returns true or false if a condition is met?

Tags: c#, conditional-statements, logic, rules

As the title states I am looking for ways to create and be able to interact with bool conditions.

I have tried predicates but they don't work.  `public static Predicate<(decimal?,decimal?)> Create(Predicate<(decimal?,decimal?)> predicate) => predicate;`

this only works as a filter for when I do `Condition.Create(c => c.IsSomeCalc(list1, list2))`

then the use case is `var res=Condition(SomeValList)`

there are many overloads for the creation of a condition and not just 1.

what I am trying to do is create a condition that returns true or false if the condition is met

i.e `Condition IsLower= Condition.Create(c=>c.IsLower(decimal,decimal)`

Then to use

```
IsLower(5,10)//=true
```

edit:
Say I have a `Condition`Class that has the field `ConditionOperator`
and `ConditionOperator` Is an interface that Implements Classes Like `IsGreaterThan` and in `IsGreaterThan` I have the field `IsTrue` which is `boolean` and in that class I can have multiple overloads for updating `IsTrue`

i.e  `public IsGreaterThan(decimal itm, decimal itm2) { isTrue = itm > itm2; }`

and then use case would be another class that use the condition like

```
Test Test= new Test();
Test.Condition.ConditionOperator= new IsGreaterThanCondition(1,2);
Console.WriteLine($"{Test.Condition.ConditionOperator.IsTrue}";
```

This is all redundant and less versatile than the extension methods for what I am trying to do.

Comment: Simply a `Func<decimal, decimal, bool>`?

Comment: Could you please clarify your question? In the title you are talking about two list objects in the question you are talking about `decimal`s.

Comment: sorry, as I mentioned there were multiple overloads of creating a condition, I just used another example, But yes primarily, I will be passing in list objects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The *Check* function.

```cs
public static void Main()
{
    List<double> listA = new List<double>() { 1, 2, 3 };
    List<double> listB = new List<double>() { 2, 3, 4 };
    
    // Simple example, checking if the sum of the numbers in list A
    // is greater than the sum of the numbers in list B.
    bool result = Check(listA, listB, (a, b) => a.Sum() > b.Sum());
    Console.WriteLine($"Test result: {result}");
}
    
public static bool Check<T>(List<T> listA, List<T> listB, Func<List<T>, List<T>, bool> condition)
{
    return condition(listA, listB);
}
```

Comment: This looks promising.

Comment: sorry, this just replaces my extension method.

Comment: This helped change the way I thought about the problem, so its the best answer

Answer (score 0):

If you have two lists and you need to compare elements in both lists, by what algorithm do you create the pairs of elements from both lists?

If you like to pair them simply by their position within the list, you can `.Zip()` them both together and then apply your condition:

```
var listOne = new[] { 1, 2, 3 };
var listTwo = new[] { 3, 2, 1 };

var pairs = listOne.Zip(listTwo, (a, b) => (a,b));
var aIsHigherOrEqualToB = pairs.Where(pair => pair.a >= pair.B);

var anyElementMatches = aIsHigherOrEqualToB.Any();
```

If your pairing is done due to some property matching (e.g. Id), than you can `.Join()` them:

```
var listOne = new[] { ... };
var listTwo = new[] { ... };

var pairs = listOne.Join(listTwo, item => item.Id, item => item.Id, (a, b) => (a,b));
var aIsHigherOrEqualToB = pairs.Where(pair => pair.a.Value >= pair.b.Value);

var anyElementMatches = aIsHigherOrEqualToB.Any();
```

Depending on your requirements you could create a helper method, that encapsulates the logic as needed:

```
public static bool AnyMatches<T>(
    IEnumerable<T> a,
    IEnumerable<T> b,
    Func<T, T, bool> predicate)
{
    var pairs = a.Zip(b, (aItem, bItem) => (aItem, bItem));
    var matches = pairs.Where(pair => predicate(pair.aItem, pair.bItem));

    return matches.Any();
}

public static bool AnyMatches<TItem, TKey>(
    IEnumerable<TItem> a,
    IEnumerable<TItem> b,
    Func<TItem, TKey> selector,
    Func<TKey, TKey, bool> predicate)
{
    var pairs = a.Join(b, selector, selector, (aItem, bItem) => (aItem, bItem);
    var matches = pairs.Where(pair => predicate(pair.aItem, pair.bItem));

    return matches.Any();
}
```

Be aware, that this is just a rough sketch. You should probably add some argument checks and other stuff to avoid exceptions, etc.

Comment: not really trying to check for matches per se in the extension methods, just want to know true or false or calculations to filter unfiltered data.

Comment: and to be able to pass those extension methods to the conditions as constructor or method